# Comparative Deletion or Participle Phrase?

Tags: grammar, coordination, participle-phrases

I have this sentence:

> We repeated the same process for the next car, *but using the product B*, and recorded the data accordingly.

I am not sure if the italicized part is grammatically correct. But if so, I think it is due to coordinate deletion (but [we repeated the same process] using the product B) or being a participle phrase. Which one is it?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to know the exact part of speech?  Most native speakers don't even know or care what is a "participle phrase" much less the more obscure "coordinate deletion".

Comment: "but using product B" or "but using the product Zoatribublan".  The definite article is used when **product** is given a name, but not when it is given merely a label.  The label does the work of the article.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the implication here is that we are saying this: 'We repeated the same process for the next car, but [we repeated the process for the next car] using product B, and recorded the data accordingly.'

I agree with Tᴚoɯɐuo— here we need 'product B', not 'the product B'.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because it is a participle phrase. You could, after all, legitimately reverse the order: "Using product B, we repeated the same process for the next car." You'd be more likely to call it a participle phrase, then. But I think you could argue that there is a form of coordinate deletion going on in all participle phrases, which is what can lead to dangling participles.

Answer (score 0):

The participle phrase is used when expressing an attendant circumstance, a circumstance that obtains during the action of the main clause.

The phrase can be introduced by **but**  to indicate a *change* in  attendant circumstance—a departure of some kind from a prior circumstance.

> Last week the roof leaked and we had water on the ceiling near the chimney. This week we had more rain and another leak, ***but* coming in through the gable window**.